# How can I reliably detect if a bonded device support GATT?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I'm trying to detect if a bonded Bluetooth Device supports [GATT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Bluetooth_v4.0) or not.

When scanning, calling `BluetoothDevice.getType()` will recognized my device as type 3 (*Dual Mode - BR/EDR/LE*). However, after the device is bonded and a call to `BluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices()`, the same method returns my device as type 1 (*Classic*).

```
@Override
public void onScanResult(int callbackType, android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult result) {
    result.getDevice().getType();// value is 3
}
...
// this will show pairing request to user
device.connectGatt(context, false, callback);
...
// once the device is paired, I query for the new set of bonded devices.
Set<BluetoothDevice> set = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBondedDevices();
for (BluetoothDevice device : set)
{
    device.getType();// value is 1
}
```

How can I reliably detect if a bonded device support [GATT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Bluetooth_v4.0) (type 3 or 2)?

I have also tried cross-checking bonded devices with:

```
int[] ALL_STATES = { BluetoohtProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED, BluetoohtProfile.STATE_CONNECTING, BluetoohtProfile.STATE_CONNECTED, BluetoohtProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTING };
List<BluetoothDevice> list = BluetoothManager.getDevicesMatchingConnectionState(BluetoothProfile.GATT, ALL_STATES);
```

But the result is always an empty list.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can double check whether the device in your scan result and bonded device is the same device.

I guess the bonded device is other BT device bonded with your Android device.